# Error in dynamoDB mapper scan() : java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-java

I am getting below error while calling

```java
dynamoDBMapper.scan(Person.class, new DynamoDBScanExpression())
```

```java
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ScanRequest.setScanFilter(ScanRequest.java)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.createScanRequestFromExpression(DynamoDBMapper.java:1692)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.scan(DynamoDBMapper.java:1569)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.AbstractDynamoDBMapper.scan(AbstractDynamoDBMapper.java:236)
```

With the same `dynamoDBMapper`, `dynamoDBMapper.save(person1)` is working fine.

The `NullPointerExecption` is coming inside of `ScanRequest.setScanFilter` method of the AWS SDK.

Although, the method `setScanFilter` has only one line of code, the stacktrace is not showing the line-number where the exception occurred.

The method ScanRequest.setScanFilter looks like this.

```java
public void setScanFilter(java.util.Map<String, Condition> scanFilter) {
    this.scanFilter = scanFilter;
}
```

Not sure how `this.scanFilter = scanFilter` can cause a NullPointerException

- Spring Boot - 2.2.6.RELEASE
- DynamoDB SDK - 1.11.555
- Java - Corretto-8.242.08.1

Comment: As a side note, the v1 AWS SDKs are pretty awful, and I strongly recommend using the v2 if possible.

Comment: Is there something removing the parts ot the stacktrace by chance?

Answer (score 0):

@ShrinivasShukla I also found the NPE when [Contrast](https://docs.contrastsecurity.com/en/get-started.html) is wired up in Application. In my case Probably Contrast is disabling/blocking scanRequest.setScanFilter(scanExpression.getScanFilter() to work.